# How to initiate a user selected clock countdown from 25 minutes?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to initiate a clock countdown from 25 minutes. while the clock ticks all FireStore interations have a timestamp that at the end of the clock is saved.How can i initiate the countdown ?

````
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

[...]

int _start = 10;
int _current = 10;

void startTimer() {
  CountdownTimer countDownTimer = new CountdownTimer(
    new Duration(seconds: _start),
    new Duration(seconds: 1),
  );

  var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
  sub.onData((duration) {
    setState(() { _current = _start - duration.elapsed.inSeconds; });
  });

  sub.onDone(() {
    print("Done");
    sub.cancel();
  });
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Timer test")),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            startTimer();
          },
          child: Text("start"),
        ),
        Text("$_current")
      ],
    ),
  );
}'''```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well there 2 options

1. Using [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html), but if your app close timer will be canceled
2. [AlarmManager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) but only for Android, with that, you can specify a date when you want to run your code, that approach will work even if the app was killed

Comment: what about ios?

Comment: 1 option will do fine on iOS. but if you want to trigger code after a long time even if an app was killed then you probably whant push notifications but its pricy